# How to escape cvs keywords in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, cvs, gnu-make

I am trying to automatically set the version in a makefile from the CVS tag. Here is relvant the part of the makefile:

```
VERSION =$Name:  $
```

That works ok when I checkout the project. The keyword is replaced by the tag. The problem is that as it is the Makefile does not work unless the keyword is substituted (i.e. the $ signs are gone), so I con not for example compile check the code before committing. 
If I escape the $ using `$$Name $$`, then the checked out version would not compile as it would become $$.

Is there a way to workaround this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GNU make, this kind of construct works:

```
COMMAV  := ,v
CVSFILE := $(patsubst %:,,$$RCSfile: Makefile,v $$)
CVSVERS := $(patsubst %:,,$$Revision: 1.130 $$)
CVSDATE := $(patsubst %:,,$$Date: 2012/10/09 22:02:16 $$)
CVSINFO := $(subst $$,,$(subst $(COMMAV),,$(CVSFILE))$(CVSVERS)$(CVSDATE))
```

In your case, you are looking for the revision, so I believe the direct solution is:

```
VERSION := $(subst $$,,$(patsubst %:,,$$Revision: 1.130 $$))
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure this solves the problem.  Perhaps some clarification on the question is in order if it does not?

Comment: I'm completely puzled with that sintax, I'll just try it out and let you know!:) . Note: I'm intrested in the "tag" i.e. -r argument when doing checkout rather than the individual file revision, that is why I'm using $Name$

Comment: I tried this:
VERSION :=$(subst $$,,$(patsubst %:,,$$Name:  $$))

After checking out with -r TEST-VERSION it got substituted to:
VERSION :=$(subst $$,,$(patsubst %:,,$TEST-VERSION$))
But the VERSION VARIABLE ended up in \"EST-VERSION\". It seems something is eating up the first char.. wait may be i'm missing the COMMAV thing..

Comment: Finally the last construct worked. I only added a strip, to avoid blanks:
`VERSION :=$(strip $(subst $$,,$(patsubst %:,,$$Name: TEST-VERSION $$)))`